# Loop through array of objects and update all values based on id in JS

Tags: javascript, arrays, for-loop, object

I am not sure if I am on the right track with this or not, any guidance on how to find the answer would be great, I want to understand this vs just be given the answer. Thanks

**Write a function called recordCleaner.
Loop over the accidents array.
Change atFaultForAccident from true to false**

Code I am given

```
var myCar = {
  make: 'Toyota',
  model: 'Corolla',
  year: 1992,
  accidents: [
    {
      date: '3/15/93',
      damage: '$5,000',
      atFaultForAccident: true
    },
    {
      date: '7/4/98',
      damage: '$2,200',
      atFaultForAccident: true
    },
    {
      date: '6/22/99',
      damage: '$7,900',
      atFaultForAccident: true
    }
  ]
}
```

My function

```
ecordCleaner=(myCar)=>{
  for(var key in myCar){
    if(myCar[key].includes('atFaultForAccident')=== true){
      return myCar[key] = false;
    }
  } return myCar;
 }
```

Comment: in your function, where is `accidents`?

Comment: Problem statement: check, own attempt: check, description of problem with own attempt: nowhere to be seen. I mean i can see, that among more problems, you are e.g. calling `includes` on something, which isn't guaranteed to be an array, or have a property `includes`, which is callable. It would however be nicer, if you would talk about problems you encountered.

Comment: I don't understand why you check if atFaultForAccident is false and then assign it to true. What you want is that you set atFaultForAccident to false and not true.

Comment: @ ASDFgerte -- I am having trouble understanding how to access and change multiple values at one time in the nested object myCar.    I originally tried a for loop with an if statement, but ran into the problem of not being able to change all of the values from true to false

Comment: I just noticed that @ lewa9, I changed it around, but am still having problems getting the value to actually change.

Answer (score 0):

Loop over `myCar.accidents` with [forEach](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach) and make it false.

To make `true` to `false` or `false` to `true`

```
c.atFaultForAccident = !c.atFaultForAccident
```

```js
var myCar = {
  make: "Toyota",
  model: "Corolla",
  year: 1992,
  accidents: [{
      date: "3/15/93",
      damage: "$5,000",
      atFaultForAccident: true,
    },
    {
      date: "7/4/98",
      damage: "$2,200",
      atFaultForAccident: true,
    },
    {
      date: "6/22/99",
      damage: "$7,900",
      atFaultForAccident: true,
    },
  ],
};

function recordCleaner(car) {
  car.accidents.forEach((c) => (c.atFaultForAccident = false));
}

recordCleaner(myCar);
console.log(myCar);
```